# Extjs if collapsed = true for Ext.panel.panel then expand is not taking proper width

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am working with Extjs 5.1.0 version, i have two panels Panel 1 and Panel 2, the First Panel should be collapible and second one should expand if panel 1 is collapsed.

By default the Panel1 should be collapsed,

```
collapsed: true
```

it is loading properly but when i am expanding the Panel1 it is not taking the right width.
you can observe the behavior in the below

[code here](http://jsbin.com/hisihav/edit?html,js,output)

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Can't reproduce in a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17u6), can you?

Comment: Please change  collapsed: true and run  items: 
{
                flex: 1,
                collapseDirection: "left",
                collapsed: true,
                expandable:true,
                title: "Panel 1"
            },
Thanks for your help

Comment: It looks like a bug with hbox layout.
Refer - https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?270412-4.2.1-GA-HBox-item-doesn-t-expand-if-it-was-collapsed-initially.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Any work around is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can give width to your panel 1 **OR** you can write a listener on Panel 1 to collapse it after render.
See working example [here](http://jsbin.com/xalogogaqu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. I applied this in my production code. It is working